# Is getting promotion using influence dharma or adharma?

Tags: dharma

In offices, people may often resort to lobbying and using influence to get a promotion in their jobs.
Will this practice be considered as adharma or dharma?

Comment: Please rephrase the question title and body, else there are more chances to get close...

Comment: you are right.The essence of dharma is 'atmanah pratikulaani pareshaam na samaacharet ' ie dont do with others  something which if done to you causes your suffering. So  getting whatever we dont deserve by unfair means is adharma

Comment: Giving personal details is not necessary in the Q .. I have edited those out .. You might edit it again, but retaining those portions might get your Q closed.

Comment: it seems to me that while giving personal advice is not allowed, the suffering mentioned in the background story of this question was really significant and should remain in the question. Suffering is universal, while promotion on merit or otherwise as a form of career progression is a scenario that relates mainly to modern life and particular fields...